# How to delete a certain string from every cell in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have four cells like this:

```
hello greg
hello nick
hello eric
hello jenny
```

and I wanted to remove the "hello" from every cell (without going through manually, of course) to get this:

```
greg
nick
eric
jenny
```

Is there any way I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is to save the excel file as a `.CSV` file, open it up with NotePad and hold `ALT` while selecting with your mouse to enable the Box Selection.  That way you can select all of the "Hello"s you want to remove at once.

You could also use `Find + Replace` and put 'hello ' in the `Find What` box, leave the `Replace With` box empty and hit Replace All

Answer (score 3):

- Highlight the Column in Excel you want to remove the "hello "s from.
- Do a Find & Replace (Ctrl+H)

  - **Find:** "hello " (without quotes, with a space at the end)
  - **Replace:** (leave this blank)
  - Hit **Replace All**

Comment: This was correct but the other guy answered quicker. Thanks though

Comment: No problem, glad you got your answer!